# Integration of Cubepoints/Achievements

Tags: buddypress

Is there some plugin or some way to integarate any of the following :

- Cubepoints
- Achievements

with either of the following :

- Favorite (default in bp)
- Vote it Up
- Emo Votes

Comment: w2lame, can you clarify what you're asking? Are you referring to specific plugins? I can't make any sense of your question.

Comment: yeah these referred to some plugins..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of the Achievements for BuddyPress plugin, and it's lucky I saw your question. I don't often read this site. I can't talk for Cubepoints, but with Achievements, it is easy to extend support to other plugins.

For developer documentation, see http://achievementsapp.com/developer/add-support-for-a-plugin-non-custom-post-type/. If either of those vote plugins are super popular and well-written, I'll add support to the core of Achievements.

Favourites (activity stream favourites, yes?) should work with Achievements. I'll put it on the to-do and check support for hte next release.

Comment: I am not sure about Emo Votes but Vote it Up is a nicely written and a popular plugin. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Dear Paul, the link you provided is not  working. Please to repair it since  many pages on the net are linking to it, and additionally, it is containing answers to a lot of developpers questions. thanks in advance.